# Do multiple calls to different methods in parallel in spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I am fetching data from several different APIs. They are rest and soap web services. I have one id that I pass to each API one by one and get data in return. But each API takes few seconds to return the result and so the final response object that I create takes too much time.

My application is a Spring 4 Rest Service. What is the best way to call all these several APIs in parallel so that my Response time reduces to as less as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel's answer is right but I would like to add something more to it. If you want to do something with your results but don't want to block with Future#get then I would suggest you to use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class.

It will let you add various actions which will be triggered on its completion. 
There is also a really nice article on how to use CompletableFuture with Spring's `@async` annotation. Here it the link. [Completable futures with Spring async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use @Async annotation. You can find an example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)